# Pandas bar plot does not show error bars with .unstack()

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have constructed a MultiIndex column Dataframe and plot it in grouped horizontal bars. The grouping is on MultiIndex level 1, which I have solved with `unstack()` for the plot.
I would like to add the xerr bar to the plot, however it is not displayed.

Here is the dataframe:

```
    level_0: observer_1           observer_2              observer_3
    level_1: meas1 meas2 meas3    meas1 meas2 meas3       meas1 meas2 meas3
index: 
val          3      1     5        2    0.5    4           2     2    4.5
std          0.1    0.2   0.01     0.15  0.01  0.2         0.03  0.1  0.01
```

Here is my code and the plot:

```
dfSTD = df.loc['std',:].to_frame()
dfVal = df.loc['val',:].to_frame()
dfVal.unstack(level=0).plot(kind='barh', ax=axis[0], xerr=dfSTD.unstack(level=0))
```

[image: Horizontal Barplot]

Comment: Can you add some code to create a dummy df we can play with? See also: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-with-error-bars

Why is your std dev transposed?

Comment: @Evan I have read this documentation. I figure something does not connect because of the unstack(). The transpose was because otherwise python threw an error that there is a dimension mismatch and accepted the transpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the values have to be taken from the dataframe, similar to this case here:
[Plotting error bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144784/plotting-error-bars-on-barplots-with-multiple-series-in-pandas)

So the plot command I was looking for is this:

```
dfVal.unstack(level=0).plot(kind='barh', ax=axis[0], xerr=dfSTD.unstack(level=0).values.T)
```

[image]