# Making seaborn.barplot by group with asymmetrical custom error bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

I have a Pandas dataframe that has a couple of group columns like below.

```
gr1 grp2 variables  lb     m       ub
 A   A1      V1     1.00   1.50    2.5           
 A   A2      V2     1.50   2.50    3.5         
 B   A1      V1     3.50   14.50   30.5           
 B   A2      V2     0.25   0.75    1.0
```

I am trying to get a separate sub-barplot for each variable in `variables` using `FacetGrid`. I am trying to build to the final plot that I need which looks like the below.

[image: Plot with FacetGrid and Multiple Categorical Variables]

This is what I have so far.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="variables", hue="grp1")
g.map(sns.barplot, 'grp2', 'm', order=times)
```

But unfortunately this is stacking all my datapoints.

How should I go about doing this with `Seaborn`?

UPDATE: The following code largely does what I'm after but currently does not display `yerr`.

```
g = sns.factorplot(x="Grp2", y="m", hue="Grp1", col="variables", data=df, kind="bar", size=4, aspect=.7, sharey=False)
```

How can I incorporate the `lb` and `ub` as error bars on the factorplot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before we start let me mention that matplotlib requires the errors to be relative to the data, not absolute boundaries. We would hence modify the dataframe to account for that by subtracting the respective columns.

```
u = u"""grp1 grp2 variables  lb     m       ub
A   A1      V1     1.00   1.50    2.5           
A   A2      V2     1.50   2.50    3.5         
B   A1      V1     7.50   14.50   20.5           
B   A2      V2     0.25   0.75    1.0
A   A2      V1     1.00   6.50    8.5           
A   A1      V2     1.50   3.50    6.5         
B   A2      V1     3.50   4.50   15.5           
B   A1      V2     8.25   12.75  13.9"""

import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), delim_whitespace=True)
# errors must be relative to data (not absolute bounds)
df["lb"] = df["m"]-df["lb"]
df["ub"] = df["ub"]-df["m"]
```

Now there are two solutions, which are essentially the same. Let's start with a solution which does not use seaborn, but the pandas plotting wrapper (the reason will become clear later).

#### Not using Seaborn

Pandas allows to plot grouped barplots by using dataframes where each column belongs to or constitutes one group. 
The steps to take are therefore

1. create a number of subplots according to the number of different `variables`.
2. `groupby` the dateframe by `variables`
3. for each group, create a pivoted dataframe, which has the values of `grp1` as columns and the `m` as values. Do the same for the two error columns.
4. Apply the solution from [How add asymmetric errorbars to Pandas grouped barplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978727/how-add-asymmetric-errorbars-to-pandas-grouped-barplot)

The code would then look like:

```
import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), delim_whitespace=True)
# errors must be relative to data (not absolute bounds)
df["lb"] = df["m"]-df["lb"]
df["ub"] = df["ub"]-df["m"]

def func(x,y,h,lb,ub, **kwargs):
    data = kwargs.pop("data")
    # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37139647/4124317
    errLo = data.pivot(index=x, columns=h, values=lb)
    errHi = data.pivot(index=x, columns=h, values=ub)
    err = []
    for col in errLo:
        err.append([errLo[col].values, errHi[col].values])
    err = np.abs(err)
    p = data.pivot(index=x, columns=h, values=y)
    p.plot(kind='bar',yerr=err,ax=plt.gca(), **kwargs)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=len(df.variables.unique()))
for ax, (name, group) in zip(axes,df.groupby("variables")):
    plt.sca(ax)
    func("grp2", "m", "grp1", "lb", "ub", data=group, color=["limegreen", "indigo"])
    plt.title(name)

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### using Seaborn

Seaborn factorplot does not allow for custom errorbars. One would therefore need to use the `FaceGrid` approach. In order not to have the bars stacked, one would put the `hue` argument in the `map` call. The following is thus the equivalent of the `sns.factorplot` call from the question.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col="variables", size=4, aspect=.7 ) 
g.map(sns.barplot, "grp2", "m", "grp1", order=["A1","A2"] )
```

Now the problem is, we cannot get the errorbars into the barplot from the outside or more importantly, we cannot give the errors for a grouped barchart to `seaborn.barplot`. For a non grouped barplot one would be able to supply the error via the `yerr` argument, which is passed onto the matplotlib `plt.bar` plot. This concept is shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385975/seaborn-factor-plot-custom-error-bars). However, since `seaborn.barplot` calls `plt.bar` several times, once for each `hue`, the errors in each call would be the same (or their dimension wouldn't match).

The only option I see is hence to use a `FacetGrid` and map exactly the same function as used above to it. This somehow renders the use of seaborn obsolete, but for completeness, here is the `FacetGrid` solution.

```
import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), delim_whitespace=True)
# errors must be relative to data (not absolute bounds)
df["lb"] = df["m"]-df["lb"]
df["ub"] = df["ub"]-df["m"]

def func(x,y,h,lb,ub, **kwargs):
    data = kwargs.pop("data")
    # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37139647/4124317
    errLo = data.pivot(index=x, columns=h, values=lb)
    errHi = data.pivot(index=x, columns=h, values=ub)
    err = []
    for col in errLo:
        err.append([errLo[col].values, errHi[col].values])
    err = np.abs(err)
    p = data.pivot(index=x, columns=h, values=y)
    p.plot(kind='bar',yerr=err,ax=plt.gca(), **kwargs)

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="variables", size=4, aspect=.7,  ) 
g.map_dataframe(func, "grp2", "m", "grp1", "lb", "ub" , color=["limegreen", "indigo"]) 
g.add_legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]